# List all subprojects in doxygen main page

Tags: cmake, markdown, doxygen

I want to have my doxygen main page to list all my sub projects and refer to their respective `README.md` file.

In every subproject's CMakeLists.txt (each project is in its own subfolder) I call the function `REGISTER_TARGET(my_project_name)` which is defined as

```
macro(REGISTER_TARGET TARGET)
    # Storing target name and directory as 2D-array
    SET(GLOBAL_TARGETS "${GLOBAL_TARGETS};${TARGET}\;${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}" CACHE INTERNAL "source_list")
    # doing other things concerning the build
    ...
endmacro(REGISTER_TARGET)
```

And in my doxygen's CMakeLists.txt I do

```
SET(DOXYGEN_GLOBAL_TARGETS "")
foreach(pair ${GLOBAL_TARGETS})
  LIST(GET pair 0 local_project_name)
  LIST(GET pair 1 local_project_dir)
  SET(local_project_readme "${local_project_dir}/README.md")

  LIST(APPEND DOXYGEN_FILES ${local_project_readme})
  SET(DOXYGEN_GLOBAL_TARGETS "${DOXYGEN_GLOBAL_TARGETS}\n- ${local_project_name}. @ref ${local_project_readme}")
endforeach()
...
CONFIGURE_FILE("${DOXYGEN_MAINFILE_IN}" "${DOXYGEN_MAINFILE}" @ONLY)
```

And my DOXYGEN_MAINFILE_IN looks like

```
This is the main page
======

Sub projects
------------
@DOXYGEN_GLOBAL_TARGETS@
```

This turns out in DOXYGEN_MAINFILE as:

```
This is the main page
======

Sub projects
------------
- name_of_project1. @ref C:/very/ugly/source/path/name_of_project1/README.md
- name_of_project2. @ref C:/very/ugly/source/path/name_of_project2/README.md
```

which does not correctly link to this file (in HTML, the whole path is shown and the last path is rendered as hyperlink but refers to an empty file). The HTML for one entry looks similar to

```
<li>name_of_project1. C:/very/ugly/<a class="el" href="da/ddd/README_8md.html">source/path/name_of_project1/README.md</a></li>
```

So

**a)** how can I turn the absolute path to a markdown file in my to a working @ref target (which also displays the first header as link text). Keep in mind, that the above file paths are *source-directory* so the doc files will reside in a completely different place.

OR

**b)** which information do i have to serialize in my REGISTER_TARGET CMake macro which can then be turned in such a hyperlink.

I know that it is theoretically possible ([OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/) does it in a quite [similar way](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/904381c602043270fc864b29dd4749c9c75effbd/doc/CMakeLists.txt#L105) but I failed to reproduce it)

Comment: Did you try to add tags in the titles of the sub pages like "This is the the first page {#frst}" and than reference this is the main page as: "- reference to first  \ref frst"? or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: I was hoping to get around that so the subproject developers don't have to check the uniqueness of their label. Kind of like the "Related pages" section can list all files even if they don't have a label